# Como montar uma página para impressão dentro do código da aplicação?

Tags: c#, winforms, impressão

Estou precisando montar uma página de impressão dentro do meu código, ou seja não vou imprimir um documento existente, e nem a tela da aplicação, quero montar na execução do código com os elementos que eu quiser.

Tenho um array e quero apenas ir adicionando textos que estão nele ao meu documento.

Sou leigo nisso e iniciei assim (não sei se é a abordagem correta):

```
    public void Imprimir(Array dados)
    {
        var documento = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

        foreach(var dado in dados)
        {
            // aqui popularia o documento com os textos pra no final so chamar o .Print()
            // não sei como fazer isso
        }

        documento.Print();
    }
```

A princípio quero apenas fazer imprimir alguma coisa para incrementar a solução e definir tamanho do papel, inserir imagens e etc...

Testei dessa forma e imprimiu a página em branco:

```
    public void Imprimir(Array dados)
    {
        var documento = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

        foreach(var dado in dados)
        {
            documento.PrintPage += meuDocumento;
        }

        documento.Print();
    }

    private void meuDocumento(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Linha 1", new Font("arial", 10), Brushes.Black, 100, 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Linha 2", new Font("arial", 10), Brushes.Black, 200, 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um formulário com um botão para execução do procedimento de criação e impressão na tela do seu relatório:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no botão faça o seguinte código:

```
private void BtnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (PrintDocument print = new PrintDocument())
    using (PrintPreviewDialog dialog = new PrintPreviewDialog())
    {
        print.PrintPage += Print_PrintPage;
        dialog.Document = print;
        dialog.ShowDialog();
    }

}

private void Print_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Image image = Image
        .FromFile(string.Format("{0}{1}", 
        Application.StartupPath, 
        "\\Arquivos\\ti.png"));

    using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 16))
    {
        g.DrawString("StackOverFlow", font, Brushes.Black, 10,20);
        g.DrawString("StackOverFlow", font, Brushes.Black, 10, 40);
        g.DrawString("StackOverFlow", font, Brushes.Black, 10, 60);
        g.DrawString("StackOverFlow", font, Brushes.Black, 10, 80);
        g.DrawString("StackOverFlow", font, Brushes.Black, 10, 100);
        g.DrawString("StackOverFlow", font, Brushes.Black, 10, 120);
        g.DrawString("StackOverFlow", font, Brushes.Black, 10, 140);
        g.DrawString("StackOverFlow", font, Brushes.Black, 10, 160);
        g.DrawImage(image, 10, 183);
    }
}
```

O método `Print_PrintPage`, fica encarregado da montagem do seu relatório na tela (ou seja, o seu Array de dados tem que ser feito ai dentro conforme código demostrando a criação de cada linha) e o resultado final desse simples relatório é:

Nesse [link (C# - Imprimindo em uma aplicação Windows Forms)](http://www.macoratti.net/09/09/c_prn1.htm) possui mais configurações e você pode modernizar ao seu gosto ...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu consigo passar outros parametros pra esse metodo Print_PrintPage??

Comment: O Print_PrintPage é um método da ação padrão do PrintDocument... Não é uma boa solução. Mas diz ai qual é a sua idéia, o que você quer fazer ?

Comment: É pq como vou montar a impressão ali eu já possuo uma lista no método anterior que quero iterar dentro do Print_PrintPage para gerar o documento de impressão.

Comment: Chame o método dentro do `Print_PrintPage`, entendeu?